# How to use Stored procedures with parameter in Mule

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, mule, mule-studio

I have a webservice that I hosted using Mule ... The webservice retrieve the data from MS SQL Data base ... I am using Mule JDBC and following configuration :-

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:conf/DBConnectionProp.properties"/>
        <spring:beans>
            <spring:bean id="DB_Source" name="DB_Source" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource">
                <spring:property name="url" value="${url}"/>
                <spring:property name="driverName" value="${driverName}"/>
            </spring:bean>
            <spring:bean id="LookUp" name="LookUp" class="com.test.MainDataDAOImpl">
                <spring:property name="dataSource" ref="DB_Source"/>
            </spring:bean>
        </spring:beans>
        <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database_Global" dataSource-ref="DB_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">
            <!-- <jdbc-ee:query key="RetriveQuery" value="Select * from getData where ID=?"/> -->
            <jdbc-ee:query key="RetriveQuery" value="CALL sp_myStoredProcedure(?) "/>
           </jdbc-ee:connector>

    <flow name="MuleDbInsertFlow1" doc:name="MuleDbInsertFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service service="MainData" serviceClass="com.test.MainData"  doc:name="SOAPWithHeader" />
    <component class="com.test.MainDataImpl" doc:name="JavaMain_ServiceImpl"/>
 </flow>
```

Now Since I am using stored procedures  **sp_myStoredProcedure(?)** I am getting exception :-

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [CALL sp_myStoredProcedure(?) ]; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:714)
    at com.vertu.services.schema.maindata.v1.Dao.MainDataDAOImpl.retrieveFromDBMethod(MainDataDAOImpl.java:102)
    at com.vertu.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl.retrieveDataOperation(MainDataImpl.java:73)
```

But if I use normal SQL query :- `Select * from getData where ID=?`  It works fine without any issue ...  In my DAOImpl class I am using the following code :-

```
 String retrieveDataFromDB = getQueryByKey("RetriveQuery"); 

jdbcTemplate.query(retrieveDataFromDB, new Object[] { ID },
                    new RowMapper() {

                        @Override
                        public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int line)
                                throws SQLException {
                            System.out.println("inside row mapper");
                            // Display records
                            dataResponse.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
                            dataResponse.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
                            dataResponse.setAge(rs.getInt("AGE"));
                            dataResponse.setDesignation(rs
                                    .getString("DESIGNATION"));
                            dataResponse
                                    .setResponse("The Data retrieved from the Database");
                            return 1;
}
});
```

Please Help ... What is the issue with Stored procedures where as normal SQL query works fine with parameter ???

Comment: Please stop bumping your question or we will be forced to lock it and that will prevent it from getting answers completely.

Comment: The issue is that bumping your question repeatedly is disruptive and inconsiderate.

Comment: Some body tried to edit my question to a format which I don't want....He tried to change my code.. I had no idea what to do as I wanted my original question to be posted ...I just tried to rollback to the original.. my intention was not to bump the question .. I just wanted to keep my original question .. people here try to edit other's question to their own format which I don't like .. so I just tried to keep my original question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tutorials:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/calling_stored_procedure.htm
- http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2013/04/spring-framework-tutorial-call-stored-procedures-from-java.html

explain how to call a stored procedure from Spring.

Comment: Thanks David ... found my mistake ... I modified the Store procedure call in the global end point as  < jdbc-ee:query key="RetriveQuery" value="exec sp_myStoredProcedure ? "/> .... JdbcTemplate works with that calling format ...

Answer (score 0):

please find the latest version mule 3.6 stored procedure call usage.

```
<db:stored-procedure config-ref="Oracle_Configuration1" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{call apps.create_sales_Order(:p_header_rec_oper,:P_order_number,:P_ordered_date,:P_line_id,:p_flow_Status_code,:P_return_status)}]]></db:parameterized-query>
            <db:in-param name="p_header_rec_oper" value="CREATE"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_order_number" type="INTEGER"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_ordered_date" type="DATE"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_line_id" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <db:out-param name="p_flow_Status_code" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_return_status" type="VARCHAR"/>

</db:stored-procedure>

{
•   P_return_status: "S",
•   P_line_id: "684229",
•   p_flow_Status_code: "ENTERED",
•   P_ordered_date: "2015-05-22",
•   P_order_number: 69393
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but this is already done and is very old thread and I was actually trying it with old JDBC component